Overfitting Issue in My CNN-Based Audio Analysis Model: Classifying Every Sound as an Ambulance with 100% Accuracy
I want to classify emergency vehicles like ambulances and fire trucks, but I believe my model is experiencing overfitting (though I'm not entirely sure).
No matter how I train my model, whether I reduce the number of epochs or decrease the dropout rate, it consistently achieves high accuracy and classifies every sound as an ambulance (even my own speech!).
How could I detect and counter this overfitting?
Or is there an error in my code?
Training
train-model.py:
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import os
import librosa
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import joblib  # To save the model
import h5py  # To save the model file

# Path to the directories where audio files are located
audio_dataset_path = "sounds/"  # Main folder
class_folders = ['ambulance', 'firetruck', 'traffic']  # Subfolders

# Feature extraction function
def feature_extractor(file):
    audio, sample_rate = librosa.load(file, res_type='kaiser_fast')
    mfccs_features = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=audio, sr=sample_rate, n_mfcc=40)
    mfccs_scaled_features = np.mean(mfccs_features.T, axis=0)
    return mfccs_scaled_features

# List to collect features and labels
extracted_features = []

# Process audio files by iterating through each folder
for class_label in class_folders:
    folder_path = os.path.join(audio_dataset_path, class_label)  # Subfolder path
    for file_name in tqdm(os.listdir(folder_path)):  # For each file in the folder
        if file_name.endswith('.wav'):  # Only process .wav files
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)  # Full file path
            data = feature_extractor(file_path)  # Extract features
            extracted_features.append([data, class_label])  # Add features and label

# After processing the data, you can convert it to a numpy array or pandas DataFrame
extracted_features_df = pd.DataFrame(extracted_features, columns=["features", "class"])

x = np.array(extracted_features_df["features"].tolist())
y = np.array(extracted_features_df["class"].tolist())

labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
y = to_categorical(labelencoder.fit_transform(y))

# Separate the training and testing data
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

# Model layers
num_labels = 3
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(125, input_shape=(40,)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(250))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(125))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(num_labels))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"], optimizer="adam")

# Train the model
epochscount = 30
num_batch_size = 32
model.fit(xtrain, ytrain, batch_size=num_batch_size, epochs=epochscount, validation_data=(xtest, ytest), verbose=1)

# Save the model
model.save("trained_model.h5")
joblib.dump(labelencoder, "label_encoder.joblib")



Training Statistics:
Epoch 25/30 accuracy: 0.8856 - loss: 0.4328 - val_accuracy: 0.9417 - val_loss: 0.1999
Epoch 26/30 accuracy: 0.8702 - loss: 0.3767 - val_accuracy: 0.9250 - val_loss: 0.1948
Epoch 27/30 accuracy: 0.8749 - loss: 0.4145 - val_accuracy: 0.9333 - val_loss: 0.1827
Epoch 28/30 accuracy: 0.8412 - loss: 0.5060 - val_accuracy: 0.9250 - val_loss: 0.1767
Epoch 29/30 accuracy: 0.8715 - loss: 0.4280 - val_accuracy: 0.9250 - val_loss: 0.1707
Epoch 30/30 accuracy: 0.8774 - loss: 0.4372 - val_accuracy: 0.9333 - val_loss: 0.1776

Inference
microphone-classifier.py:
import tensorflow as tf
import librosa
import numpy as np
import joblib
import sounddevice as sd
import wavio
import time

# Load the model
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("trained_model.h5")
labelencoder = joblib.load("label_encoder.joblib")

# Microphone parameters
duration = 3  # Recording duration (seconds)
fs = 44100    # Sampling rate (Hz)

# Function 1: Records audio and writes it to a file
def record_and_save_audio(filename, duration=3, fs=44100):
    print(f"Recording {filename}...")
    recording = sd.rec(int(duration * fs), samplerate=fs, channels=1, dtype='float32')
    sd.wait()  # Wait until the recording is complete
    wavio.write(filename, recording, fs, sampwidth=2)  # Save the audio file
    print(f"{filename} has been recorded.")

# Function 2: Classifies the recorded audio file
def classify_audio(filename):
    # Classify the new audio file
    sound_signal, sample_rate = librosa.load(filename, res_type="kaiser_fast")
    mfcc_features = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=sound_signal, sr=sample_rate, n_mfcc=40)
    mfccs_scaled_features = np.mean(mfcc_features.T, axis=0)

    # Reshape the input to the expected shape of the model (1, 40)
    mfccs_scaled_features = np.expand_dims(mfccs_scaled_features, axis=0)

    # Make predictions
    result_array = model.predict(mfccs_scaled_features)

    result_classes = ["ambulance", "firetruck", "traffic sound"]

    # Print prediction probabilities for each class
    print("Classes and Prediction Probabilities:")
    for i, result_class in enumerate(result_classes):
        print(f"{result_class}: {result_array[0][i]:.2f}")

    # Check the highest prediction probability
    max_confidence = np.max(result_array[0])  # Highest prediction probability

    # If max prediction probability is below 80%, return "traffic sound"
    if max_confidence < 0.80:
        print("\nResult: traffic sound (Prediction Probability is below 80%)")
    else:
        # If above 80%, perform normal classification
        result_index = np.argmax(result_array[0])
        confidence = result_array[0][result_index]  # Highest prediction probability

        # Print the result and the highest prediction probability
        print(f"\nResult: {result_classes[result_index]} (Highest Prediction Probability: {confidence:.2f})")

# Loop to record audio every 3 seconds and classify it
try:
    i = 1
    while True:
        filename = f"sounds/recording_{i}.wav"  # Name of the audio file to be saved
        record_and_save_audio(filename, duration, fs)  # Get audio recording
        classify_audio(filename)  # Classify the recorded audio
        time.sleep(3)  # Repeat the loop every 3 seconds
        i += 1
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Audio recording and classification has been stopped.")


OUTPUT:
Recording sounds/recording_1.wav... 
sounds/recording_1.wav has been recorded. 
1/1 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 59ms/step 
Classes and Prediction Probabilities: 
ambulance: 1.00 
firetruck: 0.00 
traffic sound: 0.00

Result: 
ambulance (Highest Prediction Probability: 1.00) 
Recording sounds/recording_2.wav... 
sounds/recording_2.wav has been recorded. 
1/1 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 19ms/step 
Classes and Prediction Probabilities: 
ambulance: 1.00 
firetruck: 0.00 
traffic sound: 0.00

Result: ambulance (Highest Prediction Probability: 1.00)

